# Column type using highchart

Tags: javascript

Even though I am poor at English, please understand me.
I am using highchart. The chart type is 'column'. My problem is in 'series' get register Date and using 'xAxis' option 'datetimeLabelFormats'. 
It wants to show "%Y-%m" on the X-axis but only the '%Y' is output.
That's my setting source code. please get me a solution. thanks.

```
enter code here

    chart: {type: 'column'},
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
            month: monthLabel,
            //year: "%b"
        },
        title: {
            text: 'date'
        },

    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'count'
        },
        min: 0
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: "<b>{series.name}</b><br>",
        pointFormat: "시간 : {point.x:"+monthLabel+"}<br>count :  {point.y:.0f}",
    },
    credits :{
        text : '',
        href : ''
    },
    plotOptions: {

    },
    series: graphData
```

Comment: sorry 'month' option is '%Y-%m'

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: sorry. my quetsion is want show '%Y-%m' in xAxis. But now just seeing  year. I want show year and month.